# Sencha Touch panel html not visible

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am running my sencha-touch/phonegap app on the emulator and when the i set the html using iframe on a panel. It is not visible. But if i switch to a different panel and come back to the original html panel. the html is visible.
 I believe its the refresh or layout issue but i cant find a way to redraw the panel.

I have already tried `myPanel.hide()` and `myPanel.show()` but the content is not visible. I have the iframe inside a div like below

```
'<div style="height:100%;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;"><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" src="'+results[i].url+'"/></div>'
```

I am setting the content of the div dynamically like below.

```
for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                    {
                        console.log("Setting the result page to "+results[i].url);
                        var url = '<div style="height:100%;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;"><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" src="'+results[i].url+'"/></div>';

                        this.getResultsTabPanel().add({ 
                            title: results[i].title,
                            id:results[i].title+(i+1),
                            itemId:results[i].title+(i+1),                              
                            html:url              
                        });
                    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share some more code

Comment: I have updated with more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution now. Instead of adding the child panels to the tabpanel right away. I create them inside like this

```
    for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                    {

                        var url = '<div style="height:100%;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;"><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" src="'+results[i].url+'"/></div>';                         
                        var result = {  
                                    title: results[i].title,
                                    id:results[i].title+(i+1),
                                    config : { 
                                        itemId:results[i].title+(i+1),   
                                    },
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    scrollable:true,
                                    styleHtmlContent : true,                                
                                    html:url                                                
                                };
                        panels.push(result);
                    }   
                    this.getResultsTabPanel().add(panels);
```

This works both on chrome browsers and emulators.